# Use Vue "this" instance within Lodash function

Tags: vue.js, lodash

Using VueJS and importing Lodash therein. When using a lodash function such as `_.forEach`, `this` within the function body refers to the lodash instance. How do I make `this` to point to the Vue component's instance instead?

```
_.forEach(records, function(val)
            {
                if (this.max_records >0) // max_records is defined in data(), so this should be the cimponent instance
                {

                }

            });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: thanks thanksd, but probably not. And may be too indepth a solution to this simple issue. @asemahle's solution solved it.

Comment: I believe this is the exact same problem and asemahle's solution is exactly one of the solutions in the accepted answer there. I would recommend reading through the post to get a better understanding of how the scope of `this` works in general.

Comment: thanks, will really have a look at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). The `this` value in an arrow function is fetched from the scope it sits inside, which in this case is the Vue component instance.

Example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello'
  },
  created() {
    // we use an arrow function, so that 'this' refers to the component
    _.forEach([1,2,3], (e) => {
      console.log(this.message + ' ' + e);
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>Look at the output in the console! We see that the correct "this" was used.</p>
</div>
```